# same function with different return to Views on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am new to Laravel and I am doing the following, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Both do the same thing but return to a different view

```php
    /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //Get all the services
    $franchises = Franchise::all();

    //Load the view and pass the services
    return View::make('franchises.index')->with('franchises', $franchises);
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexTwo()
{
    //Get all the services
    $franchises = Franchise::all();

    //Load the view and pass the services
    return View::make('admin.usertemplate')->with('franchises', $franchises);
}
```

And this is my route.php

```
Route::get('admin/logout', array('as' => 'admin.logout', 'before' => 'user', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogout'));
Route::get('admin/login', array('as' => 'admin.login', 'before' => 'is_guest', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));
Route::post('admin/login', array('as' => 'admin.login.post', 'before' => 'is_guest', 'uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin'));


//---- Backedn Index
Route::get('admin',array('as'=>'index','uses'=>'BackendController@getIndex'));
```

Comment: Also, are your really stuck on 3?

Comment: @JosephSilber I added the route.php for you to see and yes I am very stuck. Actually you can see it

Comment: @Monica, it's not obvious what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples represents two controllers methods.In isolation, they don't do anything. They depends on Route (not provided) and Model(Franchise).

This can be improved in a number of ways, depending on your domain logic layer design.

You could for example do this:

```
return View::make("franchises.index",compact("franchises"));
```

or this:

```
return View::make("franchises.index",["franchise"=>$franchises]);
```

But it is all variation of same thing. Further it can be improved by applying repository pattern which gives you more flexibility when dealing with database. i.e. not depending on one ORM (eloquent).

As I sad, everything depends on your goals. Controller is just a door to you domain logic.

UPDATE TO YOUR UPDATE:

You can group your routes in one controller:

```
Route::resource("admin","AdminController");
```

And please move from laravel-3.

Comment: I feel like I am going crazy trying to understand how this works. if the same function getting all the franchises is used in 2 different views, I can manage that just by using routes?

Comment: Monica please, if you want to use this awesome framework, take some time and watch some tutorials and read some books. Laravel has advanced architecture implemented inside. In order to use it you will have to dig deeper into various area - from HTTP protocol to MVC and service oriented architecture. Of course,if you want to master Laravel.

Comment: Thanks! I already bought a book, and I've been watching tutorials but can't find a way to solve this.

Comment: I think View composer will work. I just found it. Ill dig more into it.

Comment: View composer is a direct relation between model and view. view is rendered directly and it is worth checking. good luck.